# Cannot run npm build in ubuntu, AWS EC2. Error: [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/blog-api/client/node_modules/.cache'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mern

I'm trying to deploy my first MERN app through AWS EC2. It has been quite the learning experience. After following a few blog posts I figured out how to get the backend running, but I am struggling to get the front end to work.

I realize this is some permission-related issue but for the life of me I can't find any method online to fix this. Essentially I will submit "npm run build" in the ubuntu aws terminal and I recieve this error everytime. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
$ sudo npm run build

> client@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

[eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/blog-api/client/node_modules/.cache'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permission of the folder `blog-api` to the current user using `chown`.

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/ubuntu/blog-api
```

and then run `npm run build`.